# QT Read file, convert to int and use as initial slider value

Tags: c++, qt, initialization, int, slider

I've made a horizontal slider, the value is being saved in a text file. After the app is closed slider resets to the initial value of "1". Using -

```
ui->horizontalSlider->setValue(read());
```

I want to read the value of the file using read() function and set it as the initial value for the slider which results in the value being restored / saved.

This is read(); function-

```
int read(){
    std::fstream readfile;
    readfile.open("bin\ram.dat");
    std::string value;
    readfile << value;
    int value2 = atoi(value.c_str());
    return value2;
}
```

After a lot of different variable types being used and few conversion it does not work. 
**Question-** how to set the initial value of slider to int located in "bin\ram.dat"? I'm a beginner so any tips or clues are more than welcome. Thanks! (I've googled it before posting and found few codes which did not work here)

Comment: Then, you want to read an integer from a file. You can do it directly with the `>>` operator: `readfile >> integerValue;`.

Comment: Thanks! Such a noobie mistake! Also I have found out that the path name has to contain double slash as one will not work. Managed to make it work.